# CVS - Cannot exec rsh error

Tags: version-control, emacs, ssh, cvs, rsh

I am trying to use `C-x v =` to compare my current buffer with the repository file. But it gives error:

```
 cvs [diff aborted]: cannot exec rsh: No such file or directory
 cvs [diff aborted]: end of file from server (consult above messages if any)
```

Yes, I haven't installed rsh. But I already set CVS_RSH to ssh. Is there any other set I could change to let me use ssh instead of rsh when working in emacs with cvs?

By the way, I can't run any CVS commands under emacs, which are run very well in termial. Here are the cvs related setup in my login bash script:

```
 81 CVSROOT=zane@dda.uxmc.edu:/home/cvs
 82 CVS_SERVER=/usr/bin/cvs
 83 CVS_RSH=ssh
 84 export CVSROOT
 85 export CVS_SERVER
 86 export CVS_RSH
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the result of <kbd>M-:</kbd>`(getenv "CVS_RSH")`<kbd>RET</kbd>? If it isn't `"ssh"`, then you need to do one of these things:

- Start Emacs from a shell that has been intialized with your login script.
- `(setenv "CVS_RSH" "ssh")` in your `.emacs` file.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. (getenv "CVS_RSH") returns nil. But when I start emacs from a shell, it returns "ssh" correctly and vc works alright. And the elisp statement in .emacs file works too. I also tested some other env varibles too. USER returns correctly while HOSTNAME doesn't. Do you know why emacs (not starting from a shell) inherits some env varibles but not the others?

Comment: Exporting an environment variable from within a shell only affects the children of that shell process, not every process. How are you starting Emacs when not from a terminal?

Comment: start emacs by click its icon on Desktop. But I set the CVS_RSH variable long time ago. There was definitely a reboot after that. So I guess how I starts Emacs doesn't really matter. And it doesn't explain why emacs returns nil for HOSTNAME either.

Comment: What operating system and desktop environment? It does explain it; the cause is probably the same.

Comment: Also, it doesn't matter how long ago you set the `CVS_RSH` variable. That change is only effective for any children of the shell you run your script in. Which doesn't include your desktop environment, apparently. What script did you set the `CVS_RSH` variable in?

Comment: I am using latest Archlinux - Linux 3.1.1-1-ARCH x86_64 and gnome 3.2.1. And I am using emacs 24.092 compiled from source code. CVS_RSH is set in a file ~/.bash_env, which is sourced by ~/.bashrc. I think shell should get the env variables and emacs inherit them from shell. That's why I was confounded.

Comment: `.bashrc` isn't necessarily run for a login shell. Try setting `CVS_RSH` in `~/.profile`.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that .bashrc again is sourced in .bash_profile, which runs for a login shell.

Comment: You are right. The problem is that `.bash_profile` is not a login shell script in Archlinux

Comment: Now I understand. `.bash_profile` is the console login script - it is not executed when login thru graphical session. `.profile` is the login script that runs in graphical session.